# Understanding the flow of the code for ArcGIS SymbolStyler Widget

Tags: javascript, widget, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a hard time understanding how to put the code from below link into my application. I am using webApp Builder for ArcGIS and I need to have SymbolStyler widget.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_symbolstyler.html

I have tried to split this into css, html and java-script and if I open these files, individually it opens but not on my app.

Not sure how to configure this with my base map. I can share some code to show you how I have split the code from above link.

Let me know if you have used this or something similar in your application and how you did it.

Comment: Add your code to your question - it's impossible for anyone to help get your code working if we can't see it. :)

Comment: @Juffy can you check this link and let me know if you have any input on this. I am not using web App Builder anymore, thank you. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340853/exporting-data-using-sketch-tool-in-arcgis-api-for-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The sample in your link is not part of Web App Builder. It's a ArcGIS Javascript API only sample. Keep in mind you will have a couple of customization to apply to the code to make it works in WAB.

You need to create a new in panel widget. Read [the documentation here](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/get-started.htm)

Insert the code from the SymbolStyler widget inside the `postCreate` method of your new widget.

Comment: Thank you for your response I am not using this webBuilder anymore, switched to JS API and looking for an answer for this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340853/exporting-data-using-sketch-tool-in-arcgis-api-for-javascript